# Printing strings (char*) loaded from file without escaped special sequences (like \n)

Tags: c, file, parsing, replace, escaping

I'm currently writing a parser for my toy language, and as a part of that parser i have written print function that well... basically prints its argument. For string constant all it does is

```
printf("%s", pointer);
```

so

```
print("\n")
```

should be executed as

```
printf("%s", ptr_to_loaded_string);
```

(more or less)

However, my current problem is, that C escapes special character sequences while reading script file. So instead of "\n" I get "\\n".

My question is: is there some way I can avoid the escaping of this sequences, and if not what's the best way to deal with them? I'm currently thinking about search and replace - replace each sequence of 2 '\' with one '\', but it may be a little problematic (string length change, reallocing, etc.) - i want to avoid that solution unless it's absolutely necessary.

edit: argh, stackoverflow escaped my example....

Comment: Does the script file contain line breaks, or the character ``\`` followed by the character `n`?

Comment: currently the script file consists of only 1 line: `print("test\n")` and that results in printing `test\n`

Comment: Right, because escape sequences are substituted only in _literal_ strings, i. e. in your C source code.

Comment: @AlexanderBakulin: are you sure of this? Isn't printf that converts "\n" to '\n'? I'd suggest his using snprintf to print to a string, and then the printf function would convert automatically. Just needed to add % to each % in the input file.

Comment: @Spidey Yes, I'm sure (and the standard agrees with me). There's an easy way to convince you: escape sequences can occur in _character_ literals as well: `char a = '\n';`. It's obvious that `a` can't hold two characters at once.

Comment: Yes, you are obviously right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that C is un-escaping your sequences -- it's that it's simply leaving them alone, so your "\n" in the input stream is read as two characters ('\' and 'n').

Here's some code I wrote *years* ago to deal with this:

```
/*
** Public Domain by Jerry Coffin.
**
** Interpets a string in a manner similar to that the compiler
** does string literals in a program.  All escape sequences are
** longer than their translated equivalant, so the string is
** translated in place and either remains the same length or
** becomes shorter.
*/

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "snip_str.h"

char *translate(char *string)
{
      char *here=string;
      size_t len=strlen(string);
      int num;
      int numlen;

      while (NULL!=(here=strchr(here,'\\')))
      {
            numlen=1;
            switch (here[1])
            {
            case '\\':
                  break;

            case 'r':
                  *here = '\r';
                  break;

            case 'n':
                  *here = '\n';
                  break;

            case 't':
                  *here = '\t';
                  break;

            case 'v':
                  *here = '\v';
                  break;

            case 'a':
                  *here = '\a';
                  break;

            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
                  numlen = sscanf(here,"%o",&num);
                  *here = (char)num;
                  break;

            case 'x':
                  numlen = sscanf(here,"%x",&num);
                  *here = (char) num;
                  break;
            }
            num = here - string + numlen;
            here++;
            memmove(here,here+numlen,len-num );
      }
      return string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have C-style special characters directly interpreted from char sequences (e.g. from an input file).  You need to write parsing logic to determine if the sequence contains the required special char sequence and treat it accordingly

*Note*: make sure you handle escaped-escape characters properly as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the GLib, you can [g_strcompress](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strcompress) your string to convert the escaped characters and then print the result.